# Changing value of the characters of an element of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array with five elements, each of which has a nine number string in it. How would I go about changing `$array[0]`?

For example, if the first element in the array had `"123456789"` and second element had `"987654321"`, how would I change the value of both at specific places, like changing the second value of both (in this case, the `2` in the first element and `8` in the second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the individual elements in each element using the array notation if they are strings:

```
arr = ["12345","54321"]
arr[0][1] # => "2"
arr[1][1] # => "4"
```